# Kafka on Windows - start service error

Tags: windows, hadoop, apache-kafka

I am trying to cleanly start Kafka 2.10 - 0.8.2.1 on Windows but I am getting an annoying error everytime I start it.

I have just installed Kafka by following the [Quick Start guide](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart) (with the exception that I have installed Zookeeper myself). Both Kafka and Zookeeper were installed very basic, on a single machine.

**Problem**
When I run the starting script:

> kafka-server-start.bat C:\kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1\config\server.properties

I get the error:

**Error**

```
[2015-07-14 17:00:45,197] WARN Error when freeing index buffer (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.kafka$log$OffsetIndex$$forceUnmap(OffsetIndex.scala:301)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:283)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:276)
        at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:535)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.resize(OffsetIndex.scala:276)
        at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:179)
        at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:67)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$loadLogs$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$7$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV
        at kafka.utils.Utils$$anon$1.run(Utils.scala:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-07-14 17:00:45,219] INFO Completed load of log test-0 with log end offset 0 (kafka.log.Log)
```

**What I observed**

When I delete the Kafka log folder, the error does not appear the first time I re-run the starting script. Kafka log folder path:

> C:\tmp\kafka-logs

I have tried to stop the service using the provided script, but it does not help. The server stop script:

> kafka-server-stop.bat

Although the same error appears when I start it the second time, Kafka start-up continues, and it seems that it works normally.

**Help**
How to get rid of the above error?

Answer (score 0):

This exception shouldn't be a problem during startup but if you want to get rid of it I guess you have to file a Jira for it.

This seems to be related to [KAFKA-1008](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1008) and [this commit](https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/c98b6de15db9a2ce72f44a5b2736f74de5066113#diff-c709d8877725f52c06396b908b438f26R300).

Answer (score 0):

```
   /**
   * Forcefully free the buffer's mmap. We do this only on windows.
   */
  private def forceUnmap(m: MappedByteBuffer) {
    try {
      if(m.isInstanceOf[sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer])
        (m.asInstanceOf[sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer]).cleaner().clean()
    } catch {
      case t: Throwable => warn("Error when freeing index buffer", t)
    }
  }
```

when index file size == 0 , cleaner where be null

see
https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/1718